# Flutter / Firebase delayed push notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello I am Jr Flutter developer.

I made chat application with Flutter and Firebase, but I having some notification problem.

Below code is how I am sending notification, when message is created in Firebase database, I am pushing notification through the firebase function.

The problem is , it's is sending notification  successfully , but Sometimes It is delayed few hours or few days!!

If which is not sending notification, I do understand , there are any bugs on my code,

But sometimes it delayed... mostly working fine.

How could I understand this situation ?  Is there any way to manage notification speed ?

Thanks for reading , I will wait for your help.

```
exports.onCreateMessage = functions.firestore//Notification
    .document('ChatRoom/{chatRoomID}/Messages/{message}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const chatRoomID = context.params.chatRoomID;
        const message = snap.data();
        const chatRoomRef = await admin.firestore().collection('ChatRoom')
            .doc(chatRoomID).get();

        //setDate to Chatroom
        chatRoomRef.ref.update({
            latestMessageID: message.messageType === CHAT_MESSAGE_TYPE_EMOJI ? '[STICKER]' : message.message,
            latestMessageTime: new Date()
        });
        const senderUserRef = await admin.firestore().collection('User').doc(message.senderID).get();
        //getUserList add  then number;
        const joinedUserList = Object.entries(chatRoomRef.data().joinedUserList);//convert obejct to map.
        joinedUserList.forEach(async (value, key, map) => {
            if (value[0] !== message.senderID) {
                const joinedChatRoomRef = await admin.firestore()
                    .collection('UserJoinedChatRooms').doc(value[0]).collection('JoinedChatRoomList')
                    .doc(chatRoomID).get();
                await admin.firestore()
                    .collection('UserJoinedChatRooms').doc(value[0]).collection('JoinedChatRoomList')
                    .doc(chatRoomID).update({
                        unReadMessageCount: joinedChatRoomRef.data().unReadMessageCount + 1,
                        latestMessageTime: new Date(),
                        isInTheChatRoom: true,
                    });
                return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(`${value[0]}`, {
                    notification: {
                        title: senderUserRef.data().name,
                        body: message.messageType === CHAT_MESSAGE_TYPE_EMOJI ? '[STICKER]' : message.message,
                        clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                        sound: 'default'
                    }
                    , data: {
                        notificationType: message.messageType.toString()
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                await admin.firestore()
                    .collection('UserJoinedChatRooms').doc(value[0]).collection('JoinedChatRoomList')
                    .doc(chatRoomID).update({
                        latestMessageTime: new Date(),
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's rather not possible that the notification is delayed with days... What do you exactly mean its delayed? Where do you check this?

Answer (score -2):

there is no speed in firebase notification as long as you submit the data to firebase and the user is online it will be displayed.

Comment: Terrible answer. First off no, the user does not have to be online for the notification to be displayed. You can configure firebase to receive notification if the app is in background or terminated. Second, why the hell would anyone wait unacceptable amount of minutes or hours for notification to arrive? Especially in a chat app. That is ridiculous.

Comment: what are you talking about i say online and you are talking about whether the app is in the background or not. there is a big difference between the two.